# Implement Coin Acceptor application for android

Tags: android, mobile, serial-port, cctalk

I want to implement Coin Acceptor application for Android using ccTalk.
But my Coin Acceptor doesn't accept the coin. I tried it on windows and it worked but on Android it doesn't

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val comPort =
            ComPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", this)

        val bus = Bus(comPort, byteArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
        val coinAcceptors = bus.coinAcceptors
        val controler = AcceptorController()

        for (acc in coinAcceptors) {
            val a = bus.createCoinAcceptor(acc, controler)
            a.run()
        }
        bus.setMasterInhibitStatusAllDevicesSync(false)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to continously poll the coin rejector using ccTalk.  If don't do that, it will not accept coins.

Comment: But how do that?

Comment: Probably the best strategy is to create a thread that does it for you in the background.